# Line styles in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

In pygame, when I draw a rectangle, corners are not filled like I want them to be. It looks like:

[image]

The problem is the same even with thick lines so I don't think it is the problem.

In another drawing library there were line styles like square or round. I searched everywhere and I couldn't find something similar. Anyone knows how this can be done without filling the corners manually?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
while True:
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), (100, 100, 100, 100), 10)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The example isn't the same as the image but corners aren't completely filled either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`draw.rect` is really just a shortcut for `draw.polygon` using the four corners of the `Rect`.  For each edge of the polygon, it draws a line of the specified width from one vertex to the next.  It doesn't go beyond the vertex when you increase the line width.  This will make it look like there are gaps in the corners for widths > 1.  If you notice there are no gaps for widths of 0 and 1.  Also notice that when increasing the line width, the lines grow on both sides (inside and outside of the specified rect).  In fact if you increase your width to half the size of the rect, you get something that looks like a cross.  If you are wanting better thick rectangles where you can specify the exact inside and outside, I'd use `Surface.fill()` for the outer `Rect` and the inside `Rect`.

---

Add example of [Surface.fill()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill)

```
window.fill((255, 255, 255), Rect(100, 100, 100, 100))  # outer rect
window.fill((0, 0, 0), Rect(110, 110, 80, 80))  # inner rect
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of Surface.fill()?

Comment: Python doesn't recognize Rect for some reason

Comment: @Atom `Rect` is part of pygame. Are you not doing the `from pygame.locals import *`?  If not you will need to use `pygame.Rect`. (`Rect` is both in the base module and in locals)

Comment: I did import pygame just like in my example. Doesn't this import pygame in whole?

Comment: @Atom it imports the default sub modules. `pygame.locals` isnt one of them.  `pygame.locals` is a 'Set of functions from PyGame that are handy to have in the local namespace for your module'.  However, if you just want `Rect` you can just use `pygame.Rect`